# Gdal_calc fails with nan output

Tags: nan, raster, gdal

I want to do some raster calculations with gdal_calc from the command line, but keep getting empty rasters filled with nan.

For example when I replace values in a raster:

```
gdal_calc.py -A input.tif --outfile=output.tif --calc="10*(A==0)+20*(A==1)"
```

In this example values equal to 0 should be replaced by 10 and values equal to 1 should be replaced by 20. Is my syntax wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Based on this: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/116473/reclassify-rasters-using-gdal-and-python

you should try:

```
gdal_calc.py -A C:temp\raster.tif --outfile=result.tiff --calc="10*(A==0)" --calc="20*(A==1)"
```